# bash script not returning return code to calling c++ program when using popen()

Tags: c++, bash, shell, popen

I have a python script that gets called in a bash script like this:

```
python3 CheckRef.py --reference $EXPECTED --result $RESULT.npy
echo "return code = $?"
```

The script prints the correct return code from the python script. For example it prints `254` if the python script returns `-2`.

However, when I call the bash script in a c++ program the return code is empty. It should be returning `-2`.

```
testClass test;
auto result = test.execute(command.c_str());
std::cout << "result is " << result << std::endl;
```

Could anybody advise what I'm doing wrong?

This is the function `execute()`

```
std::string testClass::execute(const char* cmd) {
        char buffer[128];
        std::string result = "";
        FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
        if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
        try {
            while (!feof(pipe)) {
                if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                    result += buffer;
            }
        } catch (...) {
            pclose(pipe);
            throw;
        }
        pclose(pipe);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The last command in the bash script is `echo`. Its exit status is `0`.

Comment: [Why `while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Your `execute` function returns a string that contains the output of the command, not the termination code.

The termination status code of the process is returned by `pclose`. Currently you discard the return value of your call to `pclose`